# The total curvature of very knotty knots

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, knot-theory

One of my favorite theorems is that of Fáry-Milnor, stating that the total curvature of a knot in $\mathbb R^3$ which is not an unknot (an ununknot) is at least $4\pi$.

Can one quantify the way in which knottedness forces an increase in total curvature?

Comment: Doesn't the theorem already quantify it? Milnor shows (Theorem 4.7) that (when all relevant quantities are finite) the minimum curvature in a given isotopy class is $2\pi$ times the "crookedness" (= bridge number).

Comment: @Anatoly, right now I do not have access to the paper: I remember vaguely its contents... that's why I was asking :)

Comment: Ah, fair enough :)

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for a theorem where "knottedness" is turned from a binary "yes/no" condition to a quantitative condition, like "the figure 8 knot is twice as knotted as the trefoil".  Then you want some kind of corrolation between total curvature and this quantitative notion of knotting?   The cheap answer would be "take the infima of total curvatures in the knot isotopy class". :)

Comment: Here is a link to Milnor's 1950 paper, "On the total curvature of knots": http://jstor.org/pss/1969467 . For those without JSTOR access, here is a summary: http://www-math.mit.edu/~hrm/fas/milnor.pdf .  And here is his 1953 paper,
"On total curvatures of closed space curves": http://www.mscand.dk/article.php?id=1381 .

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Fields medalist Michael Freedman got involved with knots using a very simple technique, assign a sort of energy integral that becomes infinite if there is a genuine self-crossing, that is if you try to force the curve to change isotopy class. The results   relate, at least, to Ryan's comment "the figure 8 knot is twice as knotted as the trefoil".

http://www.jstor.org/pss/2946626

Excerpts from a column by Ian Stewart...the quoting process does not seem to have rendered the mathematical symbols very well, and I do not know what the letter p means, but here is the link:
http://www.fortunecity.com/emachines/e11/86/knotprob.html

> But it now looks as if the most
>   interesting "energy" concept for knots
>   is not elastic, but electrostatic, as
>   suggested in 1987 by S. Fukuhara of
>   Tsuda College, Tokyo. Imagine the knot
>   to be a flexible wire of fixed length,
>   which can pass through itself if
>   necessary and which has a uniform
>   electrostatic charge along its length.
>   Because like charges repel each other,
>   a knot that is free to move will
>   arrange itself so as to keep
>   neighbouring strands as far apart as
>   possible in order to minimise its
>   electrostatic energy. This minimum
>   energy value is the invariant.
>
> But is it a useful one? Does it have
>   simple, natural properties that
>   mathematicians can exploit? In 1991,
>   Jun O'Hara of Tokyo Metropolitan
>   University proved that the minimum
>   energy of a knot really does increase
>   as the knot becomes more complicated.
>   Only a finite number of topologically
>   different knots exist with energy less
>   than or equal to any chosen value.
>   This means that topological types of
>   knots can be "ordered" in terms of
>   their energy. There is a natural
>   numerical scale of complexity for
>   knots, ranging from simple knots at
>   the low energy end to more complicated
>   ones higher up.
>
> What are the simplest knots? In the
>   most recent issue of the Bulletin of
>   the American Mathematical Society, a
>   team of four topologists - Steve
>   Bryson of NASA's Ames Research Center
>   in California, Michael Freedman and
>   Zhenghan Wang of the University of
>   California at San Diego, and Zheng-Xu
>   He of Princeton University- prove that
>   the simplest knots are exactly what
>   you would expect. They are "round
>   circles"- that is, circles in the
>   everyday sense. Topologists, whose
>   "circles" are usually bent and
>   twisted, have to append an adjective
>   to remind themselves when, as in this
>   case, they are not.
>
> The energy of a round circle is 4, and
>   all other closed loops have higher
>   energy. Any loop with energy less than
>   $6 \pi + 4$ is topologically unknotted - it
>   is a bent circle. More generally, a
>   knot with $c$ crossings in some
>   two-dimensional picture has energy at
>   least $2 \pi c + 4,$ though this bound is
>   probably not the best possible, as the
>   lowest known energy for an overhand
>   knot is about 74. The number of
>   topologically distinct knots of energy
>   $E$ is at most $(0.264) x (1.658)^E .$

Comment: Looking at the original article (http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1993-28-01/S0273-0979-1993-00348-3/), $p$ is $\pi = 3.14159...$. Stewart's article (from 1993!) must have been corrupted in the process of putting it on the web.