# On the total curvature of a knot

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

If the fundamental group of the complement of a knot  in $\mathbb R^3$ has $n$ generators, must its total curvature be atleast $(2π)n$ ?
            ( Milnor,in his 1950 paper "On the total curvature of knots"  http://jstor.org/pss/1969467, has shown how to assign an integer termed as *crookedness*  to a knot and that crookedness is related to the total curvature of the knot. I am not sure about the relevence, though.)

Comment: See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/32245/the-total-curvature-of-very-knotty-knots I believe your question is essentially answered there although you need to relate crossing number to minimal number of generators.

Comment: The crookedness as defined by Milnor  is the expected number of the restriction to the knot of a  random linear function on $\mathbb{R}^3$, where the randomness is  uniform in terms of their unit normal   defining a linear function.

Comment: @RyanBudney : I also believe that crookedness  in fact equals n, the number of generators.

Comment: @LiviuNicolaescu : Could you provide a reference for this fact ? It seems very interesting and reminds me of the Cauchy-Crofton formula. Thanks for the response.

Comment: http://www3.nd.edu/~lnicolae/knot-curv.pdf

Comment: If the fundamental group has $n$ generators, then the bridge number (=crookedness) is at least $n$, which implies the minimal curvature is at least $2\pi n$ (Theorem 4.7 in Milnor's paper).

Comment: Somewhat related and possibly of interest: Gonzalez and Maddocks, "Global curvature, thickness, and the ideal shapes of knots," Proc. Natl. Acad. Sci. USA 96 (1999) 4769, https://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/og/PUBLICATIONS/paper_GlobCurv.pdf